# resource 'drawable/$avd_hide_password__0' has invalid entry name '$avd_hide_password__0 using aapt2 command?

Tags: android, apktool, aapt2

I am trying to compile the apk file resources using aapt2 command but I am getting error "has invalid entry name '$avd_hide_password__0:" Please help me to resolve this issue.

C:\IMS\Demo>aapt2 compile -o arg --dir res

error: resource 'drawable/$avd_hide_password__0' has invalid entry name '$avd_hide_password__0.
error: resource 'drawable/$avd_hide_password__1' has invalid entry name '$avd_hide_password__1.
error: resource 'drawable/$avd_hide_password__2' has invalid entry name '$avd_hide_password__2.
error: resource 'drawable/$avd_show_password__0' has invalid entry name '$avd_show_password__0.
error: resource 'drawable/$avd_show_password__1' has invalid entry name '$avd_show_password__1.
error: resource 'drawable/$avd_show_password__2' has invalid entry name '$avd_show_password__2.
error: resource 'drawable/$ic_launcher_foreground__0' has invalid entry name '$ic_launcher_foreground__0.
res\values\public.xml: error: file failed to compile.